# Why can't I do math inside of MAX() in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

`MAX(Table[one])` works fine. But when I try `MAX(Table[one]*Table[two])`, or even more simply `MAX(Table[one]*2)`, it returns `#VALUE!`. It looks good in the evaluator until the very end. Why so??

Comment: What are `Table[one]` and `Table[two]`- show examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply *Tables* is just like multiplying their *range equivalents*.  For example, say our two ranges are **A1:C3**  and  **E5:G7** *(
note they are both 3x3)*.  We can use:

```
=MAX(A1:C3*E5:G7)
```

in **E1**, but it must be array-entered:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

Use the same technique with the **numeric part** of your Tables.